# How to read a specific row in a CSV File in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have searched for the last few days to try and find help for this and have found nothing.

I am studying A Level computer science at the moment. The project is a currency converter and I was wondering how to have a user input a currency code and then have program take this information and compare it to a CSV file. If the currency code is in the file I then need for the program to take a conversion rate that matches the currency code from the input and use this in a sum/equation to complete the conversion. I have tried a few different ways to try and implement a CSV file but i can't seem to get it to work.

I am using Python 3.5.2

I'm not asking for the entire code just for some examples of how to implement such a CSV file.

This is an example of one of my CSV files:

```
Currency,        Code,  Rate
Canadian Dollar, CAD,   1.3457
Swiss Franc,     CHF,   1.0129
British Pounds,  GBP,   0.8056
Japanese Yen,    JPY,   111.52
Bitcoin,         BTC,   0.001351
```

My first program used if, elif and else statements to achieve the conversion however because I finished the task so early I was told to use a CSV File instead.

This was the initial code:

```
def Amount_Input():
    while True:
        try:
            global amount
            amount = float(input("Enter amount to be converted:"))
            Currency_From()
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Entry, Please enter a valid entry as a decimal number.")
            continue


def Currency_From():
    currencyInput1 = input("Enter the currency you wish to convert from:")
    if currencyInput1 in ['USD', 'usd']:
        USD()
    elif currencyInput1 in ['GBP', 'gbp']:
        GBP()
    elif currencyInput1 in ['EUR', 'eur']:
        EUR()
    elif currencyInput1 in ['BTC', 'btc']:
        BTC()
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")
        Currency_From()


def USD():
    currencyInput2 = input("Enter the currency you want to convert to:")
    if currencyInput2 in ['GBP', 'gbp']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "USD to GBP.")
        converted_amount = amount*0.81
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['EUR', 'eur']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "USD to EUR.")
        converted_amount = amount*0.94
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['BTC', 'btc']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "USD to BTC.")
        converted_amount = amount*0.0013
        print(converted_amount)
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        USD()


def GBP():
    currencyInput2 = input("Enter the currency you want to convert to:")
    if currencyInput2 in ['USD', 'usd']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "GBP to USD.")
        converted_amount = amount*1.24
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['EUR', 'eur']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "GBP to EUR.")
        converted_amount = amount*1.17
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['BTC', 'btc']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "GBP to BTC.")
        converted_amount = amount*0.0017
        print(converted_amount)
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        GBP()


def EUR():
    currencyInput2 = input("Enter the currency you want to convert to:")
    if currencyInput2 in ['USD', 'usd']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "EUR to USD.")
        converted_amount = amount*1.06
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['GBP', 'gbp']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "EUR to GBP.")
        converted_amount = amount*0.85
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['BTC', 'btc']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "EUR to USD.")
        converted_amount = amount*0.0014
        print(converted_amount)
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        EUR()


def BTC():
    currencyInput2 = input("Enter the currency you want to convert to:")
    if currencyInput2 in ['USD', 'usd']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "BTC to USD.")
        converted_amount = amount*746.20
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['GBP', 'gbp']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "BTC to GBP.")
        converted_amount = amount*600.89
        print(converted_amount)
    elif currencyInput2 in ['EUR', 'eur']:
        print("You are converting", amount, "BTC to EUR.")
        converted_amount = amount*704.36
        print(converted_amount)
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        BTC()


print(Amount_Input())
```

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd read the whole file at the start and create a dictionary mapping currency code to rate.

Comment: Maybe you can dowload this and check their implementation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CurrencyConverter/0.5

Answer (score 1):

I know for a school project you'll need to practice your python skills but stuff like this is already captured by existing libraries. Numpy is possibly the #1 go to library for anything with numbers. This is how I would tackle your project:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
```

the following line does all the file reading and decoding

```
d = np.recfromcsv('currencies.csv', delimiter=',')
```

now you can use 'd' to access your individual currencies.

```
print( d[1] )   # shows: (b'Swiss Franc', b'     CHF', 1.0129)
print( d[1][2] )# shows: 1.0129
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [documentation on using csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

You can see in the first example they give it reads in line by line. (you shouldn't need to specify delimiter or quotechar if it's a normal csv)
For your file it should look something like this:

```
import csv
with open('currency.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    currencyreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in currencyreader:
        print row
```

And the output will be:

```
['Currency', 'Code', 'Rate']
['Canadian Dollar  CAD 1.3457', 'CAD', '1.3457']
['Swiss Franc  CHF 1.0129', 'CHF', '1.0129']
['British Pounds   GBP  0.8056', 'GBP', '0.8056']
['Japanese Yen   JPY  111.52', 'JPY', '111.52']
['Bitcoin  BTC 0.001351', 'BTC', '0.001351']
```

You set your opened file to the csvfile object. Then read in the contents of the file into the currencyreader object. Then loop through it row by row.

You will have to change the functions from reading user input to taking the row as a parameter.

Also, this may just be a personal preference but I would refactor your code to remove the while True because they make me cringe.